# How to handle text copy/pasted from Word

Tags: forms, ms-word, text-formatting

We have a textbox where users will be entering reviews. They should be able to do simple formatting things like bold, italics, lists, headers, etc... Our problem is that the majority of our users will most likely create their reviews in MS Word then copy/paste the text to our form. As you know, this can (and mostly will) cause problems when displaying the data. What is the best way to provide the simple formatting functionality without having problems when they copy/paste from Word?

The best solution would be some type of filter that takes text from Word and strips out everything unneeded or illegal.

Comment: Oh, getting stuff from Word like that is a *pain* if you want it to have any semblance of consistency. Seriously consider something more like BBcode or Markdown or what-have-you.

Comment: Unfortunately, our user base (and thus our requirements) dictates that we must have ability to copy in from Word.

Comment: Is the "textbox" receiving the buffer element of an MS Office application (Word?) as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You could write an add-in that exposes a single button with the text "Copy for Review".  Your add-in would do all the cleanup that you'd want.